# Planning to run DAGed manual job in gitlab's pipeline

Tags: gitlab, directed-acyclic-graphs, manual

I have a pipeline with manual approved deployment's job for dev stand with dependencies (by "needs' keyword). The desision when to run this job is made by the developers. But they need to monitor the status of dependencies when they want to run manual job.

Is it possible to approve manual job at the starting of pipeline and once all dependencies are completed manual job runs automatically?